# dev_appserver.py doesn't work with failure in an old ruamel.yaml included in the Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-sdk

With Google Cloud SDK 209.0.0, dev_appserver.py does not work.
Reading the traceback concludes that it is a failure of the third party library
ruamel.yaml 0.15.41, causing re to raise an exception.
See [the issue of ruamel.yaml](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/issues/204/regex-error-bad-character-range-starting) for its root cause.

Is there any way to avoid the error, other than replacing ruamel.yaml locally?

I'm using python 2.7.15 from homebrew.

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving? Can you provide more information in which stage you are receiving the error?

Comment: "sre_constants.error: bad character range" is the last line of the trace back as in the linked issue. If you want to know what calls ruamel.yaml function, it is google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/yaml.py. The error happens just after run the command, so I saw nothing but the trace back.

Comment: From the link in the description it looks like this is caused by non-ascii characters. Could you run this [Hello World](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/hello_world) and confirm if it gives you the same error. In any case provide the full trace of the error and a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).